# Dynamic handler update in Clojure Ring/Compojure REPL

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop, ring, compojure

I've created a new Compojure Leiningen project using `lein new compojure test`. Web server is run by `lein repl` and then

```
user=> (use 'ring.adapter.jetty)
user=> (run-jetty test.handler/app {:port 3000})
```

Routes and app handler specification is trivial:

```
(defroutes app-routes
  (GET "/*.do" [] "Dynamic page")
  (route/not-found "Not Found"))

(def app
  (wrap-defaults app-routes site-defaults))
```

Now, after changing anything in `app-routes` definition (e.g. changing "Dynamic page" text to anything else, or modifying URI matching string), i do not get the updated text/routes in the browser. But, when changing `app-routes` definition slightly to

```
(defn dynfn [] "Dynamic page fn")
(defroutes app-routes
  (GET "/*.do" [] (dynfn))
  (route/not-found "Not Found"))
```

i do get dynamic updates when changing the return value of `dynfn`. Also, following the advice from [this article](http://www.learningclojure.com/2011/03/hello-web-dynamic-compojure-web.html) and modifying the `app` definition to

```
(def app
  (wrap-defaults #'app-routes site-defaults))
```

(note the `#'` that transparently creates a var for `app-routes`)  also helps!

Why is that so? Is there any other way one could get a truly dynamic behaviour in `defroutes`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`#'app-routes` is a reader macro that expands to `(var app-routes)`. When a var is used as if it were a function, it is dereferenced anew on each invocation, and then the value returned by that deref is called.

If you were to supply `app-routes` as the argument, the compiler would give the dereferenced value to `wrap-defaults`, and when the var is updated, the previous value is not changed, so changing the var does not change the behavior of `app`.

The following repl transcript might be instructive:

```
user=> (defn foo [] "original")
#'user/foo
user=> (defn caller [f] #(f))
#'user/caller
user=> (def call-foo-value (caller foo))
#'user/call-foo-value
user=> (call-foo-value)
"original"
user=> (def call-foo-var (caller #'foo))
#'user/call-foo-var
user=> (call-foo-var)
"original"
user=> (defn foo [] "changed")
#'user/foo
user=> (call-foo-value)
"original"
user=> (call-foo-var)
"changed"
```

Comment: Thanks for a perfect explanation. I'd actually wish it were included in more Ring/Compojure tutorials. Thanks so much!